# trouble parsing xml ,cannot get .find to work in python ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I am trying to extract information from an XML file but I am struggling.

```
<players root="resources/gfx/characters/costumes/" portraitroot="resources/gfx/ui/boss/" bigportraitroot="resources/gfx/ui/stage/">
    <player id="0" name="Isaac" skin="Character_001_Isaac.png" hp="6" bombs="1"  items="302,105" portrait="PlayerPortrait_01_Isaac.png" bigportrait="PlayerPortraitBig_01_Isaac.png" skinColor="-1" />
    <player id="1" name="Magdalene" skin="Character_002_Magdalene.png" costume="7" hp="8" items="302,45" portrait="PlayerPortrait_02_Magdalene.png" bigportrait="PlayerPortraitBig_02_Magdalene.png" skinColor="-1" />
    <player id="2" name="Cain" skin="Character_003_Cain.png" costume="8" hp="4" keys="1" items="302,46" portrait="PlayerPortrait_03_Cain.png" bigportrait="PlayerPortraitBig_03_Cain.png" skinColor="-1" />
    <player id="3" name="Judas" skin="Character_004_Judas.png" costume="9" hp="2" coins="3" items="302,34" portrait="PlayerPortrait_04_Judas.png" bigportrait="PlayerPortraitBig_04_Judas.png" skinColor="-1" />
    <player id="4" name="???" skin="Character_006_Bluebaby.png" hp="0" armor="6" items="302,36" portrait="PlayerPortrait_06_BlueBaby.png" bigportrait="PlayerPortraitBig_06_Bluebaby.png" skinColor="2" />
    <player id="5" name="Eve" skin="Character_005_Eve.png" costume="10" hp="4" items="302,122,117" portrait="PlayerPortrait_05_Eve.png" bigportrait="PlayerPortraitBig_05_Eve.png" skinColor="-1" />
    <player id="6" name="Samson" skin="Character_007_Samson.png" costume="13" hp="6" items="302,157" portrait="PlayerPortrait_07_Samson.png" bigportrait="PlayerPortraitBig_07_Samson.png" skinColor="-1" />
    <player id="7" name="Azazel" skin="Character_008_Azazel.png" costume="11" hp="0" black="6" card="1" portrait="PlayerPortrait_08_Azazel.png" bigportrait="PlayerPortraitBig_08_Azazel.png" skinColor="1" />
    <player id="8" name="Lazarus" skin="Character_009_Lazarus.png" hp="6" card="40" portrait="PlayerPortrait_09_Lazarus.png" bigportrait="PlayerPortraitBig_09_Lazarus.png" skinColor="-1" />
    <player id="9" name="Eden" skin="Character_009_Eden.png" costume="12" portrait="PlayerPortrait_09_Eden.png" bigportrait="PlayerPortraitBig_09_Eden.png" skinColor="-1">
        <hair gfx="Character_009_EdenHair1.png" />
        <hair gfx="Character_009_EdenHair2.png" />
        <hair gfx="Character_009_EdenHair3.png" />
        <hair gfx="Character_009_EdenHair4.png" />
        <hair gfx="Character_009_EdenHair5.png" />
        <hair gfx="Character_009_EdenHair6.png" />
        <hair gfx="Character_009_EdenHair7.png" />
        <hair gfx="Character_009_EdenHair8.png" />
        <hair gfx="Character_009_EdenHair9.png" />
        <hair gfx="Character_009_EdenHair10.png" />
    </player>
    <player id="10" name="The Lost" skin="Character_012_TheLost.png" hp="0" armor="1" coins="1" portrait="PlayerPortrait_12_TheLost.png" bigportrait="PlayerPortraitBig_12_TheLost.png" skinColor="0" />
    <player id="11" name="Lazarus II" skin="Character_010_Lazarus2.png" hp="2" items="302,214" portrait="PlayerPortrait_10_Lazarus2.png" bigportrait="PlayerPortraitBig_10_Lazarus2.png" skinColor="-1" />
    <player id="12" name="Black Judas" skin="Character_013_BlackJudas.png" black="4" portrait="PlayerPortrait_BlackJudas.png" bigportrait="PlayerPortraitBig_BlackJudas.png" skinColor="1" />
</players>
```

I am trying to extract the data values of items that are in `<player>` which are all in root `<players>`

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

def mainparse (self,file,param):
    if os.path.exists(file):
        isaac = etree.parse(file)
        players = isaac.findall('player')
        print players
        for c in players:
            player =  c.find('player').text
            print ("{0}".format(player))

    else:
        print ("file doesnt exist")

mainparse("players.xml", "a")
```

It works okay (this isn't extracting items value yet just whats in `<player>`), but it doesn't work with the error:

```
player =  c.find('.//player').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

It is very confusing because it seems to work for everyone else. If i am doing it very wrong what is the correct method?

Comment: That's right, none of your XML nodes contains an attribute named "text". It's not entirely clear what information you want to extract from the file, please go into more detail about that.

Comment: Where It says <player id , I would like to print the whole of that line and eventually extract the part where it says  items="302,105"?

Comment: so you want to extract all the `items` values? The XPath for that would be `//player/@items`, or you could keep your own loop and use `c.items`. I'm not sure what "printing the whole line" is supposed to accomplish, though. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: So how would I go about implementing that i'm not too sure.

Comment: Well, `for items in c.findall('//player/@items'):` would be a start, if the `items` attribute interests you. Or `for player in c.findall('//player'):` and `player.get("items")`, if that suits you more.

Comment: It really doesn't like for items in          





    c.findall('//player/@items'):



    SyntaxError: cannot use absolute path on element

Comment: `isaac.findall()` I meant, of course. I'm trying to give you an idea of the *concept* here, that means you can't blindly copy and and paste without any understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get the value of the `items` attribute for each `player` element:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as etree

root = etree.parse("players.xml")
players = root.findall('player')
for p in players:
    items = p.get("items")  
    print items
```

Output:

```
302,105
302,45
302,46
302,34
302,36
302,122,117
302,157
None
None
None
None
302,214
None
```

Comment: Thanks , I wasnt really aware of .get , should have read the documentation properly before rushing